# Sending MySql data as part of SMS body, Twilio API using php

Tags: php, mysql, twilio

Hello am trying to send a message containing access value(code) to clients using Twilio API the access value(code) is stored in MYSQL Db however once I execute my code the SMS I get does not have the access Value**(code)** below is my code

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$account_sid = 'ACc9ff';
$auth_token = '7f1ffa';
// In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
// $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    
   //connect to the database  
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "jk47531_voucher", "Mmmm0;4", "u825147531_voucher");  
    
      

$sql ="SELECT code FROM plan50 WHERE 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$sms = $row['code'];

  
$twilio_number = "+18647963358";
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);  
$client->messages->create(
   
    // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
    '+25XXXXXXXXXX',
    array(
        'from' => $twilio_number,
        'body' => "your Voucher code is $sms"
    )
);
```

Comment: `$sms = $row['code'];` - where is `$row` supposed to magically come from here ...? You executed your query, but you failed to actually _fetch_ the data from the result.

Comment: Review a tutorial on how to output data from a mysql query using PHP/mysqli. Or there are examples right there in the PHP documentation too, there's no need to struggle with this. The issue has nothing to do with twilio or SMS, specifically. Some nice simple examples can be found here: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#fetch

Comment: Your code appears to expose sensitive credentials. Please edit is to use placeholders (such as `<placeholder>` in lieu of these sensitive values.

Answer (score 1):

Made some adjustments and created this works magic

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxx2fcdeb3ae9';
$auth_token = '7xxxxxfc1293e1cfe7032a';
// In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
// $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","api");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT code FROM plan50 ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$c= $row["code"];


// A Twilio number you own with SMS capabilities
$twilio_number = "+1864xxxxxx";

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->messages->create(
    // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
    '+2xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    array(
        'from' => $twilio_number,
        'body' => $c
    )
);

  }
} 


echo $c;
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```